# How to optimally distribute multiset into submultisets with a given sum

Tags: java, algorithm, multiset

There is a sorted multi set of N integers where N<26, for example:
[1x4,2,5x2,6x2,15,55]
And some sum - for example 10. I would like to get maximum number of sub multi sets from above set that are at least equal to given sum. For example:

1. [1x3 + 2 + 5] = 10 - first sub multi set
2. [5 + 6] = 11 - second multi set
3. [15] - third multi set
4. [55] - fourth multi set

1,6 - leftovers.
(but as you can see this is not the only answer).
What is the best way to approach this problem? I'm trying to solve this problem in java but any solution with explanation would be appreciated.

Edit:
Currently I am trying below approach:

1. Create single element multi sets that are higher or equal too sum. Remove them from original set.
2. Find 2 element sub multi sets that are exactly equal to sum. Remove them from original set <- I'm at this point
3. And now I do not know how to progress or is my approach correct.

   The question is in which point should I start accepting sub multi sets that are higher than sum and how to check if this wont cause loss of some multi sets that would be possible to create otherwise?

For now I have something like this:

```java
private static String findAndRemoveMultisetsEqualTo(SortedMultiset<Integer> numbers, int searchForSum) {
    String answer = "";
    if (numbers.lastEntry().getElement() >= searchForSum) {
        answer += "\nSet of " + searchForSum + " [" + numbers.lastEntry().getElement() + "]";
        numbers.remove(numbers.lastEntry().getElement());
        answer += " => " + String.valueOf(numbers);
        return answer;
    } else {
        answer += findAndRemoveExactPairSumInMultiSet(numbers, searchForSum);
    }
    return answer;
}
private static String findAndRemoveExactPairSumInMultiSet(SortedMultiset<Integer> numbers, final int searchForSum) {
    String answer = "";
    List<Integer> tempList = numbers.stream().filter(number -> number <= (searchForSum / 2)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (Integer number : tempList) {
        if (numbers.contains(searchForSum - number) && (!number.equals(searchForSum - number))) {
            answer += "\nSet of " + searchForSum + " [" + number + "," + (searchForSum-number) + "]";
            numbers.remove(number);
            numbers.remove(searchForSum - number);
            answer += " => " + String.valueOf(numbers);
        } else if (number.equals(searchForSum - number) && numbers.contains(number) && numbers.count(number) > 1) {
            answer += "\nSet of " + searchForSum + " [" + number + "," + number + "]";
            numbers.remove(number, 2);
            answer += " => " + String.valueOf(numbers);
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Any code already available? Because it doesn't help if **I** program you a solution here. **YOU** should try and I should help you afterwards ...

Comment: I am asking more about *A WAY* to solve this problem rather than programing that for me. Anyway attached some edit. Code is irrelevant for me at this moment.

Comment: A couple of somewhat important questions :) Is an approximate solution acceptable? N is the number of unique elements of multiset or the total number of elements? Is the sum (in the example - 10) in any way restricted?

Comment: 1. Approximate solution is **NOT** acceptable. I mean - any distribution which yields optimal number of sub-multi-sets is correct - well almost - The number of leftovers is also important - it should be as low as possible. 
2. **N** is **number of total elements** in multi-set
3. Sum is restricted to lower or equal to 20.